# Transferring a string from one .cpp file to another

Tags: c++, qt

Good evening, I working on a project that requires me to use a string variable in one .cpp file and same string variable in the next .cpp file. This is my patientdatabase.cpp:

```
void patientDatabase::on_tableView_view_activated(const QModelIndex &index)
{
 QString value = ui->tableView_view->model()->data(index).toString();
 patientR.connOpen();
 QSqlQuery qry;
 qry.prepare("select * from imageTable where PatientId = '"+value+"'");
if (qry.exec()){
    IVDB *x = new IVDB;
    x->show();
}
```

This function basically changes windows to IVBD whenever I click on patientId on the table provided in my patientDatabase and now I need the string 'value' in my IVBD.cpp

```
QSqlQuery *qry = new QSqlQuery(registration.db);
qry->prepare("select * from imageTable where PatientId ='"+value+"'");    // this string 'value; is from the last .cpp file
```

I dont want to use global variables but stuck here and not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can think of would be using [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html). In `on_tableView_view_activated` you should emit a signal and catch it in `IVBD.cpp`.

Using global variables doen't sound good, though it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use global variable it is better share your classes and we can think with your current design. Otherwise there is a global approach below.

You will define a global variable named `value` in a header file and you will use `extern` keyword while defining. It means that there is a global `value` variable that is created once and every .cpp file includes that header will use same variable. Let me write an example.

Think you have `common.h` file defining your string value:

```
extern std::string value;
```

And you have two different .cpp files they share that common value. In file1.cpp create that `value`.

*file1.cpp:*

```
#include "common.h"

std::string value;

void fooInFile1() {
    value = "Changed from fooInFile1!";
}
```

*file2.cpp*

```
#include "common.h"

void fooInFile2() {
    value = "Changed from fooInFile2!";
}
```

In this example file1.cpp and file2.cpp are affecting the same `value` variable.